# Can Google Cloud Vision generate labels in Spanish via its API?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

say that I have images and I want to generate labels for them in Spanish - does the Google Cloud Vision API allow to select which language to return the labels in?

Answer (score 3):

### Label Detection

Google Cloud Vision APIs do not allow configuring the result language for label detection. You will need to use a different API like [`Cloud Translation API`](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) to perform that operation instead.

### OCR (Text detection)

If you're interested in text detection in your image, Google Cloud Vision APIs support `Optical Character Recognition` (OCR) with automatic language detection in a [broad set of languages listed here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages).

For `TEXT_DETECTION` and `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` requests, [you can provide `languageHints` parameter in the request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#imagecontext) to get better results for certain cases where the language is unknown and/or not easily detectable.

> `languageHints[]`
>
> string
>
> List of languages to use for `TEXT_DETECTION`. In most cases, an empty
>   value yields the best results since it enables automatic language
>   detection. For languages based on the Latin alphabet, setting
>   languageHints is not needed. In rare cases, when the language of the
>   text in the image is known, setting a hint will help get better
>   results (although it will be a significant hindrance if the hint is
>   wrong). Text detection returns an error if one or more of the
>   specified languages is not one of the supported languages.

The [`DetectedLanguage` information](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#detectedlanguage) is available in the request to identify the language along with a confidence value.

> ```
> Detected language for a structural component.
>
> JSON representation
> {
>   "languageCode": string,
>   "confidence": number,
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the insights about OCR/Text Detection. Nonetheless, my question was about the "Labels" generated by Google Vision (for instance, if you submit a photo of a sunset scenery, Google Vision's API will return labels like "sunset", "beach", ... (I tested with one of my photos, and it returned up to 15 labels). Will Google Vision's API return labels in Spanish?? Thanks again

Comment: Actually, what I am looking for is a Spanish return of https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels

Comment: @1lucas - Sorry about misreading your question. Looking at the API, all the language related parameters are related to text detection and not for label detection. You will need to use a different API like `Google Cloud Translation API`(https://cloud.google.com/translate/) to perform that operation instead.

Comment: thanks - I thought about something similar (get labels in English via Vision API, and then translate them to Spanish using the Translate API).